# Symbols changed in conversion from QGIS to Webmap

Tags: qgis, symbology, embeddable-web-maps

When I convert a map in QGIS to a webmap, the symbols are changed--the size is ok, but all the specific symbols-- stars, diamonds, etc.--are converted to circles. Does anyone have suggestions on how I might address this?

Comment: webmap there are many ways to do this in QGIS can you describe your process? screenshots help

Answer (score 1):

If you use qgis2web, it doesn't export the basic point shapes. However, if you can use SVGs for your markers, qgis2web can export those.

**Update**

qgis2web now exports some of the basic marker shapes - introduced in qgis2web v2.21.0.